# Prove that if $p$ is prime and $a^7-b^3=p^2$ then $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

> Prove that if $p$ is prime and $a^7-b^3=p^2$ then $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Highest common factor, he means that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: Are you familiar with Bezouts Lemma?  $ma + nb=k$ will mean that $k$ is a multiple of $hcf(a,b)$.  So $a^7 - b^3= p^2$ means $p^2$ is a multiple of $hcf(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $q$ is a prime which divides both $a$ and $b$ then $q^3$ divides $p^2$. A contradiction.

So there is no prime that divides $a$ and $b$ and thus $\gcd (a,b)=1$.

Comment: Is this an empty conclusion, i.e., are there perhaps no integers $a,b$ with $a^7-b^3=p^2$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde All integral solutions to $a^7 - b^3 = c^2$ are [known](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508174v1); the only possible prime values of $c$ are $3$ ($1^7 - (-2)^3 = 3^2$) and $71$ ($2^7 - (-17)^3 = 71^2$).

Answer (score 1):

Well the $hcf(a,b)$ will divide both $a^7$ and $b^3$ so it will divide $a^7 - b^3$ so it will divide $p^2$.  But $p$ is prime so....

What are the only divisors of $p^2$?  $hcf(a,b)$ will have to be one of these.

For each of these choices what do you get when you look at $\frac {a^7}{hcf(a,b)} - \frac {b^3}{hcf(a,b)} = \frac {p^2}{hcf(a,b)}$?

Which of those choices will allow this to be true?

===

Are you familiar with Bezouts Lemma?  $ma + nb=k$ will mean that $k$ is a multiple of $hcf(a,b)$.  So $a^7 - b^3= p^2$ means $p^2$ is a multiple of $hcf(a,b)$.

So $a^6*\frac {a}{hcf(a,b)} - b^2\frac {b}{hcf(a,b)} = \frac {p^2}{hfc(a,b)}$.  So that means $\frac {p^2}{hfc(a,b)}$ is also a multiple of $hcf(a,b)$.

So $a^5 (\frac {a}{hcf(a,b)} )^2 - b(\frac {b}{hcf(a,b)})^2 = \frac {p^2}{hcf^2(a,b)}$.  So that means that $\frac {p^2}{hcf^2(a,b)}$ is *also* a multiple of $hcf(a,b)$.

So $a^5(\frac {a}{hcf(a,b)} )^3- (\frac {b}{hcf(a,b)})^3 = \frac {p^2}{hcf^3(a,b)}$ is an integer.

How can $\frac {p^2}{hcf^3(a,b)}$ possibly be an integer?